# Display do TextView

Tags: android, android-studio

Sempre que eu passo um certo limite de caracteres não consigo mais visualizar o texto na tela de design, se eu executar o app consigo ver, mas gostaria de ve-lo nesta dela pra não precisar ficar executando o emulador.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tente sincronizar novamente o projeto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está vendo o preview em um `Nexus 5X`, tente trocar para outro modelo com a tela maior, provavelmente este seja seu problema!

Comment: Mudei para TV e apareceu, mas não seria isso um problema? Porque era só o texto se adaptar ao tamanho e descer a tela o resto, ficando cortado. Tentei até mesmo adicionar um ScrollView mas o texto continua assim, sem parecer...

Comment: Você tem que declar o `layout_height` como `wrap_content` e utilizar o atributo `maxLines` para delimitar quantas linhas deseja no seu TextView... caso não queira que quebrar linha, dá para usar o `ellipsize="end"`